# use withRouter with createContainer and use history

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-dom

I am working on a logout functionality with Meteor/React

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

const PrivateHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header__content">
        <h1 className="header__title">{props.title}</h1>
      <button className="button button--link-text" onClick={ props.handleLogout() }>Logout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

PrivateHeader.propTypes = {
  title: propTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleLogout: propTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default withRouter(createContainer(() => {
  return {
    handleLogout: () => {
      Accounts.logout(),
      this.props.history.push('/')
    }
  };
}, PrivateHeader));
```

However I am getting an error

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
    at Object.handleLogout (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=e7e6866f8eccc90d612186214db7d5c0717e09d5:843:38)
    at PrivateHeader (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=e7e6866f8eccc90d612186214db7d5c0717e09d5:828:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=4b565562fa4100dc773fad2b7836f486fe1cb6aa:11904:16
```

I am not sure how to get around this error. I have tried using const history= createHistory() with no effect.

The dependencies I am using are:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.3.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using React Router DOM. Why not use the `browserHistory` method from 'react-router'?

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

And then

```
Accounts.logout();
browserHistory.push('/');
```

Comment: I am now getting a can not push of undefined error.

Comment: @user8768174 Are you sure you are running the code properly? Have you removed your `this.props.history.push('/')` ? If you are correctly importing `browserHistory` you can't get that error. The errors tells you that you are trying to call the method `push` on something that is undefined

Comment: I finally figured it out it was a stupid error I had to pass props into createContainer